# Establish that U1 and U2 are independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $Y_1$ has a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha_1$ and β, that $Y_2$ is gamma distributed with parameters $\alpha_2$ and β, and that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent. Let $U_1 = Y_1/(Y_1 + Y_2)$ and $U_2 = Y_1 + Y_2$.

How to Establish that U1 and U2 are independent?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You can easily compute their joint pdf $f(u_1,u_2)$ using a standard multivariate change of variables from your multivariate calculus course.  Now show that the joint pdf factors as $f_1(u_1)$ and $f_2(u_2)$ where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the marginal pdfs.